# I have a difficulty with my consult my consult in php

Tags: php, mysql

I want to put a consult like this :

```
SELECT Id_usuario, Usuario, pregunta, Respuesta  from usuario where Usuario = ?, pregunta= ?, Respuesta= ?
```

the error that appear is this :

> PDOStatement::execute(): SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: number of bound variables does not match number of tokens

I want to know how can I  made a consult with a lot of terms.

Comment: your bound number must be equal to your token for example you have 4 bound then your token must have also have 4 token.

Comment: Give this a read: https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_and_or.asp

Comment: Where is the rest of your code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the next :

```
SELECT Id_usuario, Usuario, pregunta, Respuesta from usuario where Usuario ='?' AND pregunta='?' And Respuesta= '?'
```